# Observable<String?> runs only first time

Tags: swift, observable, rx-swift

My Structure,

```
internal struct KeychainManager {    
    static private(set) var accessToken: String? = nil
}
```

My UI bind code,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let observableToken = Observable.just(KeychainManager.accessToken)

    observableToken
        .debug()
        .map { $0 == nil }
        .bind(to: authenticateButton.rx.isEnabled)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

When my app opens, `authenticateButton` can be seen enabled, but when I make API call then after saving my token successfully in `KeychainManager.accessToken`, `authenticateButton` still remains enabled. Why?

What's going wrong here?

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`. just` takes an argument and sends it as `.next` and then send `.completed` right after the `.next`. It means that `.just` called only once. But you need really observe every change of `accessToken` value. Two ways to achieve that:

1. by using notifications: post notification when it changed and use rx notification wrapper to handle changes;
2. by using any of `*Subject`. In this case, after `accessToken` set you should manually call `subject.onNext(accessToken)` (send event that `accessToken` changed) and handle this `subject` in your controller.

Comment: `Subject` can be used to make a bridge between functional and imperative code. I would definitely chose this over notifications !